# BMC remedy user tool through java

Tags: java, remedy

I am trying to get report from active link in one BMC form.

[image: user tool sample form]

How do I implement this in eclipse.

All I need is to enter Start date and end date and generate the report through eclipse.

Here is the piece of code that I've already have:

```
ARServerUser server = new ARServerUser();
String formName= Constants.FORM_NAME;
server.setServer(Constants.EMS_IP);
server.setUser(Constants.EMS_USER_NAME);
server.setPassword(Constants.EMS_PASSWORD);
//server.setPort(8080);
connect(server, formName);
```

Comment: Not sure, what kind of help do you need, with your development tools, or with the code?

Comment: in BMC remedy tool, when i click on generate license report button, i get the pop-up window which asks for start date and end date. and when i click on Generate report it creates an csv file in the server with the data. i just need to automate this process in Java. I will be connecting to the tool and providing the start and end date in java and it must route to generate report button and fetch the report.

Comment: Beware that by using your own class "Constants" you are overriding the class `com.bmc.arsys.api.Constants`

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the active link from the Java API. You can look at what command is run when the button is clicked,and try to emulate that...

A quick look in Developer Studio reveals that the csv is "saved" as an attachment on the Display-Only Form "AR System Licenses Console"

[image: Developer Studio screengrab showing Related workflow for button]

A little further digging reveals that the command executed is 
`"produse.exe -q -i ARServer\Db\LicenseReport.txt -o ARServer\Db\ReportResult.csv"`
[image: command being executed]

I would recommend running it on your server via powershell script or something instead of going through the API.

If you still insist on going via the API, then look at the workflow triggering the "License Process" filters and trigger it, or emulate it by creating your own workflow.